# Unreachable statement, and a never ending countdown

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to finish this program and it is telling me that in my main method, the `fallItem.trackingMethod();` is an unreachable statement and I cannot figure out why....

Also, my countdown timer is supposed to stop at 0 but just goes negative and won't stop till I hit stop on the program.

Any pointers are appreciated, I've been learning java all of about 5 weeks now... I have to be missing some small detail here....

**Countdown part:**

```
System.out.println("Countdown");
for (int i = 5; 1 >= 1; i--) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

**MyTrajectoryProjector class:**

```
public class MyTrajectoryProjector {
    public static double HEIGHT_THRES = 600;

    public static double startingPosition() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        double aPosition;

        do {
            System.out.printf("\n\nEnter the initial position (must be over 600.0 feet): ");
            aPosition = keyboard.nextDouble();
            if ((aPosition <= HEIGHT_THRES)) {
                System.out.printf("Error - position too low. Try again.");
            }
        }
        while ((aPosition <= HEIGHT_THRES));

        return aPosition;
    }

    public static double startingVelocity() {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        double aVelocity;  //user entered position

        do {
            System.out.printf("\n\nEnter the initial velocity (-500.0 ft/sec or more): ");
            aVelocity = keyboard.nextDouble();


            if ((aVelocity <= MyFallingItem.TERM_VELOC)) {
                System.out.printf("Error - velocity too low. Try again.");
            }
        }
        while ((aVelocity <= MyFallingItem.TERM_VELOC));

        return aVelocity;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("This program will calculate the position and velocity "
                + "of a falling object \nuntil it reaches " + HEIGHT_THRES
                + " feet above ground.");

        double aPosition = startingPosition();
        double aVelocity = startingVelocity();

        MyFallingItem fallItem = new MyFallingItem(aPosition, aVelocity);

        System.out.printf("\n\n");

        System.out.println("Countdown");
        for (int i = 5; 1 >= 1; i--) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        fallItem.trackingMethod();
        System.out.printf("object reached " + HEIGHT_THRES + " feet after "
                + fallItem.getTimeNow() + " seconds. \n The object's final "
                + "position is " + fallItem.getPosNow() + " feet.");
    }

}
```

**MyFallingItem class:**

```
public class MyFallingItem {
    private final double INI_POS;    //needs to be a constant
    private final double INI_VEL;    //needs to be a constant
    private int timeNow;    //current time
    private double posNow;   //current position
    private double velNow;   //current velocity
    public static double TERM_VELOC = -500;   //terminal velocity (-500 feet/sec)

    //MyFallingItem constructor
    public MyFallingItem(double aPosition, double aVelocity) {
        this.INI_POS = aPosition;
        this.posNow = 0.0;
        this.INI_VEL = aVelocity;
        this.velNow = 0.0;
        this.timeNow = 0;
    }

    public int getTimeNow() {
        return timeNow;
    }

    public double getPosNow() {
        return posNow;
    }

    public void updateMethod() {
        timeNow++;

        //V(t) = –32t + V0 (current velocity)
        velNow = -32 * timeNow + 0.0;
        if (velNow < TERM_VELOC) {
            velNow = TERM_VELOC;
        }


        if (velNow > TERM_VELOC) {
            posNow = +500;
        } else {
            //P(t) = –16t2 + V0t + H0 (current position)
            posNow = Math.pow(-16 * timeNow, 2) + INI_VEL * timeNow + INI_POS;
        }

    }

    public void trackingMethod() {
        System.out.printf("The initial position is " + INI_POS);
        System.out.printf("The initial velocity is " + INI_VEL);

        this.updateMethod();
        while (this.posNow >= MyTrajectoryProjector.HEIGHT_THRES) {
            System.out.printf("Object released from %.1f" + this.INI_POS + " feet at an "
                    + "initial velocity of %.1f" + this.INI_VEL + " ft/sec");
            this.updateMethod();

            System.out.printf("    at " + this.timeNow + " seconds, position is %.1f"
                    + posNow + " and velocity is %.1f" + this.velNow + " ft/sec");

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
for (int i = 5; 1 >= 1; i--)
```

with:

```
for (int i = 5; i >= 1; i--)
```

---

The second argument in a for loop is the **required condition**. The condition you defined is: `1 >= 1` which is **always** true.

You forgot to change the condition so it would check the value of variable `i`, therefore, you are entering an *infinite loop*, and that is no good!

---

[Quick reference about for loops in java.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: Took me a while to notice this `1 >= 1`. I was about to comment that these two lines are the same :)

Comment: Wow I knew it was something simple... Becuase of the never ending loop from hell, it could never reach the `fallItem.trackingMethod();`

Answer (score 1):

*@Evin1_* gave you the correct code (edit: and now added an explanation), but I want to provide an explanation.

He is right: `for (int i = 5; 1 >= 1; i--)` is the broken code, but here is why.  The expression that controls how long the loop runs for, `1>=1`, is **always** true.  And because you have this, you are essentially writing a [`while(true)`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/124176/whats-the-term-for-whiletrue-loop-with-break-inside) loop that decrements `i` at the end, which is why

> [it] just goes negative and won't stop till I hit stop on the program

Comment: I see, thank you guys for the info, it still amazing how very detailed you have to be. I was staring at this for what seemed like forever and didnt see it

Comment: @Newb2Java i, j, l, 1 are sources of trouble